# deleting model in app context raises sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object user is already attached to session

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query a user from the database then delete it. However, I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<User at 0x249c4a15290>' is already attached to session '3' (this
> is '4')

```py
@app.route("/user/<user_id>", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_user(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()

    with app.app_context():
        db.session.delete(user)
        db.session.commit()

    return {}
```

I used `with app.app_content` because I saw somewhere that it was required to avoid an outside of context error.

Answer (score 0):

Flask-SQLAlchemy scopes the `session` to the current app context. Accessing `session` in different app contexts will return different sessions. A view function already executes in an app context. Then you pushed another one manually. You've queried in one context, then called delete and commit in another.

Remove `with app.app_context()`, it's unnecessary here. You only need to push an app context if you need to do something outside of a request or CLI command, such as initial setup.